# Web Api. Multiple actions were found that match the request. How to add custom endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have rest Web Api controller with CRUD. And I need to add a custom POST endpoint:

```
public class TherapistController : ApiController
    {
       public IHttpActionResult Post(TherapistModel therapistModel)
        {
           return Ok(therapist);
        }

        public IHttpActionResult SendConfirmationEmail(TherapistModel therapistModel)
        {
            return Ok(therapist);
        }
    }
```

But in this case I have an error: "Multiple actions were found that match the request".

Here is WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "internal",
                routeTemplate: "internal/api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Here is my API calls:

```
axios({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: '/internal/api/therapist/',
            data: this.state.newTherapist
        });

 axios({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: '/internal/api/Therapist/SendConfirmationEmail/',
            data: this.state.newTherapist
        });
```

Comment: For which call do you get this error ? When calling `SendConfirmationEmail` ?

Comment: for this request `/internal/api/therapist`

Comment: Do you have any other action in `TherapistController` that are not shown here ?

Comment: Yes, I have `Get` `Get(int id)` `Put` and `Delete` actions

Comment: Does it work if you explicitely put `[HttpPost]` above `IHttpActionResult SendConfirmationEmail(TherapistModel therapistModel)` action ?

Comment: No... Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Attribute routing in these cases, where you have Multiple Action methods for same http verb .

Below will work,

Add this line above all defined routes in Register Method

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  // Enable Attribute Routing Web API routes

and define routes as attributes..

```
[RoutePrefix("internal/api/therapist")]
public class TherapistController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Post/{therapistModel}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(TherapistModel therapistModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Email/{therapistModel}")]
    public IHttpActionResult SendConfirmationEmail(TherapistModel therapistModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

In you JS calling code..

internal/api/therapist/post/{yourparameter}

and

internal/api/therapist/email/{yourparameter} 
....to call above methods accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: '/internal/api/therapist/', // remove '/' from last form both url
        data: this.state.newTherapist
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would solve the issue mentioned in the question ?

Comment: he need to pass parameters after action name not '/'.